# How to validate column while creating Table?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

Need to validate the column while creating the tables in postgres , An example before developer create table We are in need to validate the Audit columns,

Example :

```
create table tab_1 (
a integer,
b integer,
Audit1 integer,
audit2 integer)
```

Should not create the tables without the audit columns , Is it possible by trigger or any other concept.

Comment: Security is not the right way to defend yourself against developers. Write a script that periodically checks for non-conforming tables and emails the DBA's,

Comment: @Andomar I don't entirely agree, actually; things like row-level security and object permissions are useful for just that. They're not to stop developers from following bad habits though, only to limit access for security sensitive information, to limit damage from accidental mass changes, etc.

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL does not support triggers on system tables, so there's no way you can write a normal trigger that fires when table definitions are changed.

PostgreSQL 9.4 introduces a new feature called [event triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/event-triggers.html). (More options have been added for event triggers in the coming 9.5 release too). You could use an event trigger to validate that table definitions follow rules you set out by writing suitable validation code in PL/PgSQL. You can query `information_schema` and/or `pg_catalog` to find details of the tables, and you can abort the transaction with an `ERROR` if you don't like what you see.

That said, this seems like a complicated technical solution to a simple people problem. I wouldn't advise going down this route when your code review process can be fixed to catch these sorts of problems, your app can be modified to query the schema and emit warnings on tables that aren't defined how you require, etc.

Comment: As a proof of concept, I tried to implement an event trigger running the check automatically with a plpgsql function, but since we (currently) can only access [`TG_EVENT` and `TG_TAG`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-EVENT-TRIGGER) (and not, for instance, the OID of the created table in any way), I couldn't find a method to identify the triggering table reliably. There are ways to guess from `pg_class` columns (biggest `oid`, `relowner`, compare `pg_class.relfrozenid` to `txid_current()`) but nothing definitive unless I am missing something ...